# C++ subtract mean from array of double

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array of double* with about 10'000 elements and have to subtract the mean value  from it. And this has to be done quit a lot.

Right now I have done it quit stupid:

```
double mt = 0;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {mt += array[i];}
mt /= n;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {array[i] -= mt;}
```

Whereby array:the big array of double & n is the size of that Array. I'm sure there is someway to implement it with some fancy characters which would be much faster and I'm hoping that you guy's can help me with that.

cheers
magu

Comment: This is going to be pretty fast. Have you tried compiling it with the highest optimization setting, and benchmarking?

Comment: Faster? Parallelize...

Comment: I don't think there's any better (better as in faster) direct way of doing it in C++ code-wise (maybe processor-wise if you do it parallel on several cores). Maybe in assembler but one would have to think about it deeply

Comment: Well it's necessarily a two pass operation, and your solution is straightforward and efficient. If by fancy you mean using std algorithms, it won't make it faster. Your options are either parallelize (have a look at [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#C.2B.2B)) or vectorize with SSE intrinsics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be done in a bit shorter way but the performance will not be noticeably better. Use `std::accumulate` from  `<algorithm>`:

```
double mean = std::accumulate(array, array + n)/double(n);
```

What you can do however is to remember the first time you compute it and then on next iterations simply subtract `(mt * n)` from the sum(assuming what you show in the question is the modification that happens between iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks fine to me.

You could use [`std::transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) but I am sure it would not make it any more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do this very often then why not just keep a running total and the number of items in the array?

Then the sum to calculate the average will be of complexity O(1).

Answer (score 0):

you can skip the computation of mean every time by keeping an active copy of the total_value. In case you have to recursively subtract the mean from the same table itself then you can use the following formula and find the total.

new_total = old_total - n * prev_mean;
new_mean = new_total / n;

Answer (score 0):

Hmm seems like there is nothing implement on low level.

Thanks anyway for you answers.